# Windows 7 IE 8 changes color

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet

In the tabbed view of IE window in Windows 7, at times the color of the tab changes to Red/green/yellow/blue. Does it convey any message to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so you can organize which tabs you opened depending on where you opened them. Like if you open a new blank tab, it'll create it in a different colour than tabs you open from another site.